# Is mapping of an @Embeddable through a wrapper @Entity possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am currently building a persistence layer for a number of data classes that I can **NOT** change. These classes have no Id property/field which makes them ill suited for being used in ORM.
A best case scenario for me would have been some sort of auto-generated Ids that would only be present inside the database to set the objects in relation to each other. Sadly this does not seem to be possible using the JPA apis.

Since the above approach did not work out, I decided on trying to use simple wrapper @Entity objects like so:

```
@Entity
public class ThirdPartyObjectWrapper {
  @Id private long id;
  @Embedded private ThirdPartyObject myThirdPartyObject;
}
```

This approach works out nicely in the database, but I am having problems getting the object out of the wrapper and into its place inside another third party object.

```
public class AnotherThirdPartyObject {
  private ThirdPartyObject object; //Actually in a Many-To-One-Relationship
}
```

Because they are third party objects I'm mapping them through the orm.xml file defining the relationships there. At this point in time the relationship mapping looks like so:

```
<many-to-one name="object"  
  target-entity="ThirdPartyObjectWrapper"/>
```

But with this setup Hibernate tries to insert the `ThirdPartyObjectWrapper.id` into the `AnotherThirdPartyObject.object` field, which obviously fails.

My question now is:
Is what I am trying even possible?